# Prove that if $0<a<b<\pi/2$ then $\tan^{-1}b-\tan^{-1} a<\tan b -\tan a$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Prove that if $0<a<b<\pi/2$ then: $$\tan^{-1}b-\tan^{-1} a<\tan b -\tan a$$

I have managed to prove that for each $x\in (0,\pi/2)$, $\tan x>\tan^{-1}x$, but I'm not sure this is the right direction

Comment: So $\tan^{-1}$? Is it $1/\tan$ or $\arctan $?

Comment: @ChristianF Not sure about the OP, but I've always seen the $T^{-1}$ notation to mean the inverse function of $T$.

Comment: yea it's $\arctan$ I think that's common practice for functions as @GaurangTandon said.

Comment: Yea, but you could write that down!

Comment: Never mind, even so the problem still holds.

Comment: Well I didn't think that it's not common notation which needs explaining :) But since it apparently holds both ways I guess it's a lucky accident.

Comment: $$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}-\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{\cos^2(x)} $$ is quite clearly less than $\int_{a}^{b}1\,dx-\int_{a}^{b}1\,dx=0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I like that way of thinking about it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using the MVT namely $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(\xi)$$ and we get
$$\frac{\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)}{x-y}=\frac{1}{1+\xi^2}$$

Comment: Ah nice! I figured it out. I don't think I would have ever thought of using the MVT. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A direct corollary of the *Mean value theorem* asserts that

> Let $I\,$ be an interval, $x_0\in I$. If two functions $f$ and $g$, defined on $I$, satisfy
>   $$\begin{cases}
> f(x_0)\le g(x_0),\\[1.5ex] f'(x)<g'(x) \enspace\forall x>x_0,\:x\in I,
> \end{cases}$$
>   then  $\;f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x>x_0$, $x\in I$.

Comment: That seems nice, but I guess I would have to prove that first :) though it doesn't seem to hard to prove.

Comment: It's fundamentally the same as proving a function takes negative values  from a negative derivative  and a non-positive initial value. Usually left the proof to the students when I had to  teach this.

Answer (score 0):

When solving i assume that $\tan ^{-1} = {1\over \tan}$ and not $\arctan $. Luckly the problem still holds.

Since $0<a<b<\pi/2$  we have $\tan (a-b)<0$ so

$$  {\tan a-\tan b \over 1+\tan a\tan b }<0$$ so

$$(\tan a-\tan b) \cdot (1+\tan a\tan b )<0$$

so $$\tan a-\tan b < \tan a\tan b (\tan b-\tan a)\;\;\;\;/:\tan a\tan b$$ 
and we get (since $0<a<b<\pi/2$ we have $\tan a>0$ and $\tan b>0$)

$$ \tan^{-1}b-\tan^{-1} a<\tan b -\tan a$$

Comment: Can you please explain how you got your third equation?

Comment: I meant this equation $\tan a-\tan b < \tan a\tan b (\tan b-\tan a)\;\;\;\;/:\tan a\tan b$ I also don't understand the slash-colon notation you've used